# Склонение названий компаний

Tags: склонение, названия

Кто-нибудь может аргументированно сказать, как склоняются русскоязычные названия фирм, не являющиеся аббревиатурами, написанные крупными буквами, без родового слова?

Напр.: Стратегически важным для «ТОПАЗА» стало развитие нового направления...

"ТОПАЗа"? "ТОПАЗ"?

Comment: Спасибо всем большое.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы начал с выяснения грамматических оснований для написания данного названия большими буквами. Таковым могло бы послужить написание его в составе заголовка или иного текста написанного прописными буквами (тогда и при склонении все буквы - большие). Если же это внеграмматическая фиксация названия (напр., юридическое требование писать его большими буквами в составе любого текста), то почему бы такое название - в интересах защиты от неблагозвучия языковых конструкций с его использованием - грамматически не адаптировать (без склонения оно звучит странно - будто за названием кроется видовое наименование женского рода)? По способу склонения можно приравнять его к буквенной аббревиатуре, ведь большинству пользующихся этим словом вряд ли интересна его этимология. Основанием же для склонения "заглавно-буквенных" аббревиатур является созвучность мужскому роду при условии читаемости по слогам. Тогда, раз это не буквенное сокращение, то это точно не "тэ-о-пэ-а-зэ", и слово нужно склонять добавлением окончания строчными буквами: **ТОПАЗа**. Пусть это будет "социальной адаптацией" слова с "ограниченнымии грамматическими возможностями".

Answer (score 1):

Первое. Не склонять нет никаких причин; склоняем.

Второе. Прописные буквы, если это не аббревиатура, не имеют права на жизнь - с точки зрения русского языка.

Третье. Прописные буквы названия вкупе с кавычками относятся к авторскому дизайну, а это уже не языковая проблема.

Четвертое. Так как в этом случае филология отдыхает, делаем, как захочет левая нога заказчика, -

показываем ему оба варианта и вопрошаем: ну и как тебе?

Мне нравится вариант со строчными флексиями.

Answer (score 0):

Склонять, конечно. Никаких проблем, непонятно, в чем может быть сомнение.

> Да, но вопрос в том, как склонять, если название дано прописными
>   буквами? С последней строчной? Все прописные?

А, черт... Слона-то я и не заметил. А вот нет у нас таких правил, как склонять названия из заглавных букв. Если бы это была аббревиатура, то понятно, но тогда бы и кавычек не могло быть.

Бог его знает, отзываю идею однозначно склонять.
Значит, не склонять. Из двух зол - меньшее.

Comment: Да, но вопрос в том, как склонять, если название дано прописными буквами? С последней строчной? Все прописные?

Comment: А, черт... Слона-то я и не заметил. А вот нет у нас таких правил, как склонять названия из заглавных букв. Если бы это была аббревиатура, то понятно, но тогда бы и кавычек не могло быть. Значит, не склонять. Из двух зол - меньшее.